# How to assign Typescript class properties to another class using Map angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi I have webapi service which return an array of type(MileStoneModel) .I want to transform that converted(MileStoneModel) object to another class in typescript which I can use to fill a drop down select list which is an directive that I will use in multiple places.Below are the structure of the both classes.

```
    This is the source object 
    export class MileStoneModel
    {
        public Id: number;
        public Name: string;
        public StartDate: Date;

    }
```

I need to convert it to below

```
    export class SelectListItem {
    constructor(id: number,
        name: string) { }
    }
```

So MileStoneModel[] needs to be converted to SelectListItem[] and Id and Name properties needs to be assigned in the SelectListItem class. My Service class which returns MileStoneModel array is below method is getMileStones() .Iwant to call this method and conert the result to SelectListItem[].

```
           import { MileStoneModel} from '../models/milestoneModel'
           import {SelectListItem} from '../models/selectListItem';
                import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http'
                import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
                import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
                import {IPagedResponse} from '../models/PagedResult';
                import {PaginatePipe, PaginationService, PaginationControlsCmp, IPaginationInstance} from 'ng2-pagination';
                import 'rxjs/Rx';



                @Injectable()
                export class MileStoneService //implements IPagedResponse<MileStoneModel>
                {

                    data: MileStoneModel[];
                    //private _page: number = 1;
                     total: number;

                    private pagedResult:  IPagedResponse<MileStoneModel>;

                    mileStones: MileStoneModel[]
                    private url: string = "http://localhost/ControlSubmissionApi/api/Milestones";
                    constructor(private http: Http) {


                    }
                    getMilestones(): Observable< MileStoneModel[]> {

                        return this.http.get(this.url)
                            .map((response: Response) => <MileStoneModel[]>response.json())            
                            .catch(this.handleError);


                    }


                    getPagedMilestones(page: number, pageSize: number): Observable<IPagedResponse<MileStoneModel>> {

                        return this.http.get(this.url + "/" + page + "/" + pageSize)           
                            .map((response: Response) => {
                              return  this.extractPagedData(response);

                            })
                            .catch(this.handleError);


                    }



                    private handleError(error: any) {
                        // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
                        // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
                        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
                            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
                        console.log(errMsg); // log to console instead
                        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
                    }



                    private extractData(res: Response) {

                        let body = res.json();
                        return body.data || {};
                    }

                    private extractPagedData(res: Response): IPagedResponse<MileStoneModel> {

                        let body = res.json();
                        console.log("result"+ body);
                        return {
                            data: <MileStoneModel[]>body.Data,
                            total: body.Total
                        }

                    }

                }
```

/// SelectListItem Directive Code ..

```
        import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
        import {NgModel, ControlValueAccessor} from "@angular/forms";
        import {SelectListItem} from '../models//SelectListItem';

        @Component({
            selector: 'ng-dropdown[ngModel]',
            //  directives: [NgIf, NgFor, NgClass],
            template: `
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="sel1">Select list:</label>
                       <select (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)"   name="dd"  class="form-control" [id]="refId">

                      <option *ngFor="let item of dataList"  [value]="item.id">
                             {{item.name}}
                          </option>    
                        </select>
        </div>
        `
        })

        export class DropDownDirective implements OnInit {
            @Input("dataSourceList") dataSourceList: SelectListItem[];
            @Input("Id") Id: string;
            dataList: SelectListItem[];
            selectedOption: number;
            refId: string;

            @Output("onSelectItem") onSelectItem = new EventEmitter();


            ngOnInit() {
                this.refId = this.Id;
                console.log("lll" + this.dataSourceList.length);
                this.createSelectList();
            }

            constructor(private selectedOptionModel: NgModel) {
                //    this.selectedOptionModel.valueAccessor = this;

            }
            onSelect(selectedId) {
                console.log("selected option:" + selectedId);
                this.onSelectItem.emit(selectedId);
            }


          public  createSelectList() {
                this.dataList = this.dataSourceList;
            }



        }
```

// template where I am using this directive

```
        <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="md-col-4"><label> MileStone Date</label>                </div>
                    <div class="md-col-4">
                                         <ng-dropdown 
              [dataSourceList]="mileStonedataSourceList" 
               [(ngModel)]="selectedMileStone" 
                [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"  
           (onSelectItem)="onMileStoneSelect($event)"  
           ngDefaultControl></ng-dropdown>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling this should get you an observable of `SelectListItem` arrays

```
mileStoneService.getMilestones()
    .map((mileStones: MileStoneModel[]) => {
        return mileStones.map(mileStone => new SelectListItem(mileStone.Id, mileStone.Name));
    });
```

Comment: I tried but it didnt worked . I have question here on the method which return Observble  of MileStone we dinit called subscribe instead just  map in order to transform it to SelectedListItem will it work ? Also how can I assign this selectListItem to array ?

Comment: Hi need to ask some detail on this . How can I bind returned array to the property in calling component , this.mileStoneService.getSelectListMilestones().subscribe(t => {
        this.dataSourceList = t;
        console.log(t);
        });   THIS I NOT WORKING .but in console I can see array of SelecListItem

Comment: @YashveerSingh the code you showed should work. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: It working fine #rob . But I am struggling to bind the result of this method to a drop down directive . when I log the result I have SelectLisItem Array , but the directive is not working well.I am adding the code of directive and html